# Tumblr: Three sections, each one displays posts with different tags

Tags: tumblr

I have a really important question for you guys. I want to use Tumblr as a CMS for my blog. But my theme has a few sections, for example 3. In section one I want to display 3 recent posts with tag X. In section two, three recent posts with tag Y, and in section three with tag Z. Of course everything on **one page** (index). I was wondering if it's even possible to do. What do you think guys, is it possible? If so, how to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the standard Tumblr theme engine, this is not possible. You might be able to put together a solution using the Tumblr API, but that would be a pretty in-depth undertaking.